# Equivalent of "hold" and "release" in hammer.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

In hammer.js 1.1.3 version I was able to use the following code perfectly:

```
        var button = Hammer(element, {
            hold: true,
            release: true
        });

        button .on('hold', function() {
            //Do something when the hold event starts
        });

        button .on('release', function() {
            //Do something when the hold event stops
        });
```

But in hammer.js 2.0 I'm struggling to find an equivalent:

```
    var button = new Hammer.Manager(element);

    button.add(new Hammer.Press({
        event: 'press',
        pointer: 1,
        threshold: 5,
        time: 500
    }));

    button.on('press', function(event) {
        //Do something when the the element is pressed after 500ms
    });

    //Possible handler when the element is released?
```

According to the documentation (http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started.html) for the new hammer.js 2.0, there are 5 recognizers:

```
    Pan, Pinch, Press, Rotate, Swipe, Tap
```

I couldn't find a appropriate recognizer that would allow release type functionality. Any thoughts, suggestions or ideas are appreciated. Cheers for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be supported in the next release, 2.0.1!
https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/commit/a764fde2e89c3af2575ae02d3af41d7787a60dc5

Comment: Nothing happens when I add an event listener to the pressup event - is this really supported? And what about a pressdown (=touchstart) event? I really think hammer.js should emit this without me hearing on the hammer.input event and testing if it is the first...

Comment: I am in the same situation. Hammer.js v2.0.4 has regressed from Hammer.js v1.x functionality in regards to touchstart and touchend. In the latest hammer  you must use press and pressup, and pressup does not fire if the user drags their finger beyond a certain threshold before releasing it.

Comment: You can also listen to panend

Answer (score 1):

Managed to achieve this functionality using 'press' (hold) and 'pressup' (release)

```
var hammer = new Hammer(this);

hammer.on("press pressup", function (ev) {

    // Hold gesture start (press)
    if (ev.type == "press") {
        console.log("Hold active");
    }

    // Hold gesture stop (pressup)
    if (ev.type == "pressup") {
        console.log("Hold inactive");
    }
});
```

Tested on Hammer.JS v2.0.8

Answer (score -2):

Using

```
$(button).on('touchend',function(e){});
```

Works on jQuery.

Comment: Nothing but this indeed worked for me. Thanks @jujiyangasli